# Decide on convergence of the series $\sum 1/r^{\ln n}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I'm not sure how to go about this problem. The root and ratio tests are inconclusive and I'm not sure how to find another sequence for the limit comparison test.

$$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{r^{\ln(n)}}$$
where $r>0$ is a constant.

Comment: I've made some edits to improve formatting of your question. Please check !!

Comment: I'm not sure whether the $x^n$ was there before the edit

Comment: No it wasn't. That was a serious glitch. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since $(a^b)^c=a^{bc}=(a^c)^b$ and $r=e^{ln(r)}$ $\Rightarrow$ $r^{ln(n)}=e^{ln(r)*ln(n)}=(e^{ln(n)})^{ln(r)}=n^{ln(r)}$.

Then everything will be easy.

$r>e$ , converges.
$r\leq e$ , diverges.

Answer (score 6):

$$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{r^{\ln(n)}} = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{e^{\ln(n)\ln(r)}} = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{\ln(r)}}$$
So this is just a p-series.

Comment: So the series converges if $\log r>1$, i.e. iff $r>e$.